# I'm having trouble playing audio in javascript at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio

So far, I have tried using this function to create a new audio element every time it is called:

```
function createAudio(src, type){
  var sound = new Audio();
  var source = document.createElement('source');
  source.type = type;
  source.src = src;
  sound.appendChild('source');
  sound.play();
};
```

That way, if you want to play a single audio file called, for example, "gunshot.mp3", but multiple times you can use this line of code:

```
createSound('gunshot.mp3','audio/mpeg');
```

This works ok, but what will happen is that when the sound is loaded a bunch of times, it will just stop running entirely. Every time that you reload the game its like rolling dice to see which sounds will or won't run, and even when it does run its patchy and inconsistent.

I'm guessing that it has something do with the html page being overloaded with new elements, so is there maybe a way to clear the elements every once and a while, like clearing a particle array so it doesn't get too long? Or is it just that my function is not correct in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: `html page being overloaded with new elements` you aren't adding elements to the DOM

Comment: off the top of my head, perhaps `sound.addEventListener('canplay', () => sound.play());` and maybe even `sound.addEventListener('ended', () => source.remove());` (to remove the source from the audio element, not sure that is at all an issue here though)

Comment: Another thing, to consider is to not load the same sound over and over

Comment: The reason that I am loading the same sound is because its a shooter game, so I need to have gunshots being constantly played when the player shoots. I will try the event listener though, and see if that works.